# Unable to Select Cognito in AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working with an application load balancer and I am trying to setup authentication through *Cognito*. I have setup the Cognito user pool, client and domain. However, when I try to add a rule in my load balancer, I am unable to select Cognito as an option.

[image: Unable to select Cognito as option]

Comment: And all the cognito entities are in the same AWS region as the balancer?

Comment: yes, they are all on the ca-central-1 region

Answer (score 0):

Check if the application load balancer listener is using HTTPS. The "Authenticate" option just pops up when

[image: Screenshot]